# c# window application layout problem

Tags: c#

Creating an application using C# 3.0. In my desktop system the application form layout is perfect. But the same application opens in my laptop, the form layout alignment is different.

How do i solve this problem.?

Comment: Are you resizing any of the form elements as the program is running?

Answer (score 2):

Probably different dpi settings on your laptop than from your desktop.  To prevent the form from looking strange at different settings, you might want to consider using a [TableLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.aspx). Using the auto-sizing capabilities will help keep things looking 'normal' at any dpi setting.

[Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/jpricket/archive/2006/04/05/winforms-autolayout-basics-tablelayoutpanel.aspx) is a decent blog post on using the TableLayoutPanel.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using something like the FlowLayoutPanel? It will change the layout of it's children dynamically based on the real estate that it is given.